# How does the C Compiler assign the linkage to a variable?

Tags: c

Sorry for my English. I'm actually a Spanish Speaker. I would like understand what controls whether a variable has internal or external linkage when the storage specifier is declared as `extern`.
My book (K N King — [C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504) 2008) states this (on p463 in the section titled "the extern storage class"):

> Determining the linkage of an extern variable is a bit harder. If the variable was declared static earlier in the file (outside of any function definition), then it has internal linkage. Otherwise (the normal case), the variable has external linkage.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: It is not clear what is not clear in that passage

Comment: Lots of linkers and their object file formats around.  [Example](https://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf), page 4-23

Comment: It seems that you have quoted the relevant passage of an explanation/definition. Do I understand correctly that not being a native English speaker (me too by the way, so I really mean this kindly) prevents you from confidently understanding it? Would then a set of examples of possible combinations of `extern` and `static` in different locations and contexts be a helpful answer? If so, please clearly ask for that. I propose this because comments above indicate that helpfully minded users do not understand what you need. Otherwise please explain what kind of answer would help you. Good luck.

Comment: See C11 [§6.9.2 External object definitions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2) for an example.  Note that the line `extern int i3 = 3;` (which the standard explicitly says is OK) generates warnings/errors from Clang (disguised as GCC) set fussy: `error: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Werror,-Wextern-initializer]`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am not OP, but you nailed why I found the passage to be difficult. What is the point of an `extern static` variable?

Comment: 6.2.2 §7 says: "If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Lundin That's true, but `extern` storage class specifier does not necessarily equate to external linkage, see 6.2.2 §4.